# how to split a string in a for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop, split

I have a list of strings that look like:

```
"Your friend Nicky thought you'd like this product from WorldStores",
"Your friend Denise Holder thought you'd like this product from BedroomFurnitureWorld",
```

and so on

I want to turn the list into just the last word of the sentence.
my attempt so far has been:

```
test = []
for i in sites:
    a = i.split('from ')
    a = a[1]
    test.append(a)
```

when I run this I get

```
a = a[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

whereas when I do it individually for each string it works

```
In: a = i.split('from ')
Out: ["Your friend Jack thought you'd like this product ", 'BedroomFurnitureWorld']

In: a[1]
Out: 'BedroomFurnitureWorld'
```

How can I do this in a for loop?

Comment: That exact code works.

Comment: Is it possible that not all strings in your list follow the `from xyz` structure? If the string does not contain the word 'from' then I believe you're left with a list of size 1, which is why index 1 is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

One of your sentences in `sites` is missing the separator:

```
>>> sentence = 'I am missing the separator!'
>>> a = sentence.split('from ')
>>> a = a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Either fix your data or guard your logic with an if-statment:

```
test = []
for i in sites:
    a = i.split('from ')
    if len(a) > 1:
        a = a[1]
        test.append(a)
```

My guess is that one of your `sites` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the last word from a sentence then the following should work.

```
test = []
    for i in sites:
        a = i.split()
        if a:
            test.append(a[-1])
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Do you mind telling me why my code didn't work?

Comment: @BlueMoon it is possible that one of your sentences doesnt have the `'from '` separator. In that case, the return value is a list containing the whole sentence as the only item.

Comment: `if a:` will evaluate to `True` for all values of `i` except an empty string.  If a separator is specified it will always evaluate to `True`.  (Try `bool(''.split('whatever'))`.)

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood it is because not all lines in `sites` match your expected format of `.*from \S+$`.

This (below) will not only work but also report the offending lines -

```
sites = [
    "Your friend Nicky, from DC, thought you'd like this product from WorldStores",
    "Your friend Denise Holder thought you'd like this product from Bedroom Furniture World",
    "Your friend Eric thought you'd like this product from",
    ]

test = []
for i in sites:
    a = i.rsplit("from ", 1)
    try:
        test.append(a[1])
    except IndexError:
        print "This input line is not kosher - \"" + i + "\""
```

Use [rsplit](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html)() with a maximum of 1 split to be on the safer side.